# JIRA API not able to run on gunicron for flask app

Tags: python, flask, jira, gunicorn, jira-rest-api

I am trying to deploy my JiraAPI flask app on gunicorn in centos VM.
i have used JIRA module for it.
Here is my class

```
class Jira:
    #initilizing the class
    def __init__(self):
        # private variables
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('jiraUtil')
        self.__email = environ.get('email')
        self.__secret = environ.get('secret')
        self.logger.debug("Connecting to Jira API")
        jira_options = {
            'server':  environ.get('baseUrl'),
        }
        self.jira_con = JIRA(jira_options, basic_auth=(self.__email, self.__secret),max_retries=0)
        if not self.jira_con:
            self.logger.error("Error connecting to Jira")
            raise ValueError("Error connecting to Jia")

    def createIssue(self,issue_dict) -> dict:
        self.logger.info("inside jira ticket creation")
        new_issue_body = {}
        try:
            new_issue = self.jira_con.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
            print('new_issue')
            new_issue_body['id'] = new_issue.id
            new_issue_body['key'] = new_issue.key
            new_issue_body['self'] = new_issue.self
            return new_issue_body
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error("Error creating SSD ticket: ",e)
            return new_issue_body
```

In my app.py

```
@app.route('/api/createTicket/', methods=['POST'])
def createTicket():
    app.logger.info('Creating Issue Ticket')
    request_data = request.get_json()
    fields_dict = request_data.get('fields',None)
    if fields_dict == None :
        return jsonify({"result":"failure","status":"400", "message":"Bad Request"}),400 
    jiraObj = JiraUtil.Jira()
    newIssueKey = jiraObj.createIssue(fields_dict)
    if newIssueKey == None:
        return jsonify({"result":"failure","status":"503", "message":"service Unavailable"}),500
    return newIssueKey,200
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

When i am running the app using `flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000`it is working fine and I am able to connect with my local postman
the logs got generated :

```
INFO:werkzeug:_[31m_[1mWARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead._[0m

* Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
* Running on http://192.168.113.24:5000
INFO:werkzeug:_[33mPress CTRL+C to quit_[0m
INFO:app:Creating Issue Ticket
DEBUG:jiraUtil:Connecting to Jira API
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): codecharlee.atlassian.net:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://codecharlee.atlassian.net:443 "GET /rest/api/2/serverInfo HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO:jiraUtil:inside jira ticket creation
```

but when i am running
`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app`
it starts, but gets an error when hitting the api

```
INFO:app:Creating Issue Ticket
DEBUG:jiraUtil:Connecting to Jira API
ERROR:app:Exception on /api/createTicket/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/app.py", line 25, in createTicket
    jiraObj = JiraUtil.Jira()
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/JiraUtil.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.jira_con = JIRA(jira_options, basic_auth=(self.__email, self.__secret),max_retries=0)
  File "/opt/ctier/JenkinsPythonAPI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 516, in __init__
    assert isinstance(self._options["server"], str)  # to help mypy
AssertionError
```

Please help

Comment: i have used "from jira import JIRA"

Comment: error shows problem in `jiraObj = JiraUtil.Jira()`. Error may suggest it can't find some option `"server"`. If it is some value in external file then Gunicorn may problem to read file. Gunicorn may run code with different `Current Working Directory` and it may search file in different place.

Comment: @furas Thank you so much for this suggestion !! iIchecked and found out that gunicorn was not able to read the file where I am storing the config details. As soon as added I added EnvironmentFile in the service file, it started working !!

Comment: You could describe it as answer below. And later you could mark you answer as accepted. This will be information for other people that problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that gunicorn is not able to read the environment variables that you have declared in the `.env` file.

So, just configure a service file app.service in `/etc/systemd/system` and add `EnvironmentFile=/path_to_env_file` under `[service]` and start the service.

For more info on configuring the env file in gunicorn service, you can see
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076295/gunicorn-environment-variable-setting).