# Not able to access gunicorn env file for python deployment in linux

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy python app in my centos7 using flask and gunicorn.
but i found that the app is not able to retrive variables from .env file.

It is working on my local vm.
I am using `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app`

pls help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, just configure a service file app.service in `/etc/systemd/system` and add `EnvironmentFile=/path_to_env_file` under `[service]` and start the service.

For more info on configuring the env file in gunicorn service, you can see
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076295/gunicorn-environment-variable-setting).